# Python class methods giving unexpected "bound instance" message instead of result

Tags: class, python-2.7

Practicing tidying up some code by making it more object oriented. I have the following object and I'm trying to learn two things. First, how to build a class effectively so that secondary functions such as `get_custard` will work, and second how to use methods like `stubby` which are internal to the class but not exposed to the user of the instance.

```
class rhubarb():
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.custard = None

    def get_custard(self,a,b):
        custard = stubby(a,b)
        return custard

    def stubby(a,b):
        stub = a + b
        return stub
```

Instead of a sum I get the following result

```
meal = rhubarb(1,2)
meal.get_custard

<bound method rhubarb.get_custard of <__main__.rhubarb instance at 0x7f6b2eb49518>>
```

Following on from a additional comments I get these additional errors when I parenthesize the method

`meal.getcustard()` gives me `TypeError: get_custard() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)` and `meal.getcustard(1,2)` gives me `NameError: global name 'stubby' is not defined`

Could someone help by telling me what I've missed here. Thanks

Comment: thanks @jonrsharpe I still get a load more errors though. So meal.getcustard() gives me `TypeError: get_custard() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)` and `meal.getcustard(1,2)` gives me `NameError: global name 'stubby' is not defined` I understand that this seems pretty basic to most people but it appears very counterintuitive to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is working code without the redundant attributes/methods (and with compliance to [the style guide](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)):

```
class Rhubarb():

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def get_custard(self):
        return self.a + self.b
```

Note the use of `self` to access attributes; the same syntax is used to access methods (e.g. `self.get_custard()`). In use:

```
>>> meal = Rhubarb(1, 2)
>>> meal.get_custard()
3
```

Note the use of parentheses `()` to **call** the method.

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe. In the actual code I need to have something like the stubby method that I don't need outside the class but that another function needs to call. Could you possibly show me how to do that?

Comment: @TahnoonPasha I have already commented on that in my answer - why don't you make an effort and try to figure it out yourself?

Comment: I will continue to give it a go although after an hour of working at it I don't seem to be able to get it to work. Thank you for your help @jonrsharpe. This is still much further along. Very much appreciated

Comment: Just got it. Thank you again. Will add to main question for completeness.

Comment: @TahnoonPasha please **don't** include answers in the question. If you have a separate answer, you *can* add your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from @jonrsharpe answer working code is shown below:

```
class rhubarb():
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def get_custard(self):
        a = self.a
        b = self.b
        return self.stubby(a,b)

    def stubby(self, a,b):
        return a + b
```

duly corrected for additional comments

Comment: That code doesn't make sense - `stubby` is **ignoring** its arguments `a` and `b` and just using the instance attributes `self.a` and `self.b` (you can easily test this - see what happens when you pass different arguments from `get_custard`). There is no point giving a method parameters if it's only going to use instance attributes. Also, you don't need to assign to temporary variables; e.g. just `return self.a + self.b`.